# Можно ли совместно использовать php и asp?

Tags: php, c#, asp.net, веб-служба

Есть десктопное приложение для работы с графикой. Реализовано на C#. Есть сайт (реализация PHP). В идеале было бы, чтобы это приложение работало, как онлайн-сервис на этом сайте. То есть мне необходимо реализовать подобный онлайн-сервис. Подскажите, возможно ли реализовать данную задачу с использованием asp? Возможно есть другие варианты решения данной задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписать разметку сайта под [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) (чисто теоретически должно хватить добавления к [html](/questions/tagged/html) разметке `ID` и `runat="server"` (Однако, работает не совсеми элементами разметки)) и подредактировать запросы в серверной части (из Вашей [webform](/questions/tagged/webform)).

К тому же, в диспетчере служб [iis](/questions/tagged/iis) можно установить поддержку [php](/questions/tagged/php). Это позволит реализовать сайт как с ***php*** - страницами, так и с со страницами ***asp.net***'а.

Вам даже будет не обязательно переписывать все страницы ***php***. Можно и совсем не переписывать. Просто к тем страницам добавить аспнетовские с уникальным названием.

**UPDATE:**

Вот пример работы ***php*** + ***asp.net***. Сам сайт открывает ***php***, а вот при добавлении имени страницы ***asp.net***'а открывается и она сама.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не стоит так злоупотреблять тегами в разметке. ответ вроде бы хороший, но читать его **невозможно**. На вопросе уже есть теги [tag:asp.net] и [tag:php], многократное повторение их в теле ответа никак не улучшит навигацию.

Comment: @PashaPash согласен. Отредактировал!

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. А в Вашем примере со скриншотами Вы использовали Open Server?

Comment: @MustaAvaruus почитайте [тут](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/sites/level3/3_1.php) про настройку. Инструменты для поднятия сайта уже частично есть в системе. Вернее, есть инструменты, чтобы скачать и установить платформу. Если надо, могу добавить в свой ответ подключение к [tag:iis] - [tag:php]